# Is it possible to get trash images,videos,audios in our flutter app?

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I wants to make a module in which I have to get access of trash data from my flutter application.

I don't find anything related to that problem yet. Moreover I used photo_manager: ^2.8.1 package

and some others packages but that not solved my problem. If it is not possible then please give me

some alternate solution in order to solve my problem. Thanks.